# In Sublime Text 2 How to view carriage return and line feed?

Tags: sublimetext2, eol

In notepad++ there is a toolbar button to switch on/off display of EOL characters, i.e. carriage return and line feed.

Can Sublime Text 2 do the similar thing?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Sublime Text does not currently support displaying EOL characters.

http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/104394-is-it-possible-to-show-all-characters-spaces-tabs-cr-lf-etc/

Comment: There are however some packages that can be installed.
https://github.com/SublimeText/LineEndings

Comment: Thanks Seanny -- but that package is for ST3 only.

Comment: @Seanny123 Also the package isn't terribly useful yet, doesn't actually display line endings.

Answer (score 51):

In case anyone is here years later, I found success with the sublime package [RawLineEdit](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/RawLineEdit).

1. Install with [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/)
2. Enter `Raw Line Edit: Toggle` into the command palette (via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)

Further documentation of features can be found in the [User Guide](http://facelessuser.github.io/RawLineEdit/usage/#user-guide).
**Note that this package is only supported in Sublime Text 3.**

Comment: Please delete this answer, it saves a lot of people wasting time to find out in the end it is only for Sublime 3. The question clearly says Sublime 2

Comment: @Hakaishin It is true the question clearly says Sublime Text 2. However, I'd like to offer a few counterpoints. 1) At least 29 people have found this answer useful. 2) Most people googling for an answer to this question are in fact using Sublime Text 3 since ST2 has not been updated since 2013. 3) This answer explicitly states that this package is only supported in Sublime Text 3. No one who reads this answer should end up having wasted their time to find this out.

Comment: FWIW - This is still relevant for Sublime Build 4121.  _"1) At least_ ***43*** _people have found this answer useful. "_

Answer (score 3):

There is a quick workaround, in the search, enable the `Regular expression` and the search value use `\n`. You will see all the line feed is highlighted.

Answer (score 3):

## 05 2021

This might not really helpful for OP question and also the question is 8yrs old and iam assuming he must have got a answer pretty early on.

This is anyone still looking for the answer to show the carriage return in Sublime text 3.

**As on May 2021 the current version is 3.2.2**

Detailed version of @Sam YC answer

### Tested in Sublime text 3

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>F</kbd> *(Windows)*
2. Select the first box 'Regular Expression (Alt+R)'
3. Also select 'Highlight matches' *(Last box with plain border)*
4. Enter `\n`

[image]

5. You should see something like this. If you do not see anything, just toggle the 'Highlight matches'.

[image]

Answer (score -13):

There is another way to achieve this.

Go to preference -> choose "settings-user"

In the file opened paste this command.

"ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save": true

Comment: That just ensures there is a new line at the end of **file** on save. It will not **display** end of **line** characters.

Comment: For what its worth this answer _can_ be deleted.  But its your choice.